# Apache Camel - java DSL - transform body to one of its fields

Tags: apache-camel

First, I'm fairly new to Camel so if what (or how) I'm trying to do here is dumb, let me know.

**CODE:**

```
from("direct:one")
        .to("mock:two")
        .process(new Processor(){ 
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange)throws Exception{
                        MyCustomObject obj = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyCustomObject.class);
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(obj.getOneOfTheFields());
                }
        })
        .to("mock:three");
```

**QUESTION:**

This processor transforms an object to one of it's fields. I know that I could replace it with simple expression but that would require me to put 'oneOfTheFields' in a string and I don't want to do that.

Is there a shorter way to do this using java code only?

Comment: Your example shows 2 lines of code to convert the body, isn't this short enough?

Comment: There is actually 7 lines of code and unnecessary anonymous class.. generally boilerplate. I imagine it's pretty common case and maybe there is something like: `.setBody(bodyAsInstanceOf(MyCustomObject.class).getOneOfTheFields())`

Comment: I don't understand why "that would require me to put 'oneOfTheFields' in a string" - you can have in a body every Object you want to, not only String

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily achieved using `setBody` and Camel [`simple`](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html):

```
from("direct:one")
  .to("mock:two")
  .setBody(simple("${body.fieldName}"))
  .to("mock:three");
```

You specify the name of the field, and Camel will use the standard accessor mechanism to set the body appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply do this:

```
from("direct:one")
    .to("mock:two")
    .setBody(body().getOneOfTheFields())
    .to("mock:three");
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Nope, return type of body() is ValueBuilder and there is no .getOneOfTheFields() on it.